# System Error &H80004005 When executing Macro in Excel

Tags: windows, microsoft-excel, macros

I get the error:

`Visual Basic: System Error &H80004005 (-2147467259)` when I execute a Macro in Excel that inserts in a database.

It doesn't happen with other Macros.

What could be happening?

Comment: Which Excel do you use 2007, 2010...

Comment: Do you get the "out of memory error" message?

Comment: I use Excel 2010, and I don't get "out of memory" message

Comment: I assume you can read from the database with no problem? Do you have the adequate permissions to do all CRUD work?

Comment: Do the other Macro's insert? If so, do they share the same connection string?